# Sum qty but result is weird in Mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I'm using MySQL query to sum `qty`, but the result a little bit weird, this is my query"

```
SELECT SUM(qty) FROM inventory_logs
WHERE product_id =12 AND `type` = 'is' AND deleted_at IS null
```

The data I want to sum:

[image]

The result:

```
4.440892098500626e-16
```

For additional info, the data type `qty` column is `VARCHAR`.

Comment: You will need to `CAST` your varchar type into a decimal type and then do a sum.

Comment: Please read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and post a complete sample, when you ask such a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as I mentioned in my comment, you will need to `CAST` your varchar values into decimal values and then sum them.

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT
    FORMAT(CAST(SUM(qty) AS DECIMAL(12,2)),2) AS qty_sum
FROM
    inventory_logs
WHERE
    product_id =12 AND `type` = 'is' AND deleted_at IS null
```

Test fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i6Z3AsTPxJ6hHABLhpQUEo/0).

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple trick to make a number of it, but because of the fractal you need also to use a Round for

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(qty + 0),2) FROM inventory_logs
WHERE product_id =12 AND `type` = 'is' AND deleted_at IS null
```

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE inventory_logs (
  qty VARCHAR(5)
);
INSERT INTO inventory_logs(qty) VALUES('0');
INSERT INTO inventory_logs(qty) VALUES('2.74');
INSERT INTO inventory_logs(qty) VALUES('1.07');
INSERT INTO inventory_logs(qty) VALUES('-3.81');
INSERT INTO inventory_logs(qty) VALUES('3.81');
INSERT INTO inventory_logs(qty) VALUES('-3.81');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(qty + 0),2) FROM inventory_logs;

| ROUND(SUM(qty + 0),2) |
| --------------------- |
| 0                     |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4yPorU6k3SjQ5nmhgi1wGo/2)

Comment: you might wanna use OP's actual 'qty' values in your fiddle, because this method will leave OP with the exact same outcome using his values, which is `4.440892098500626e-16`

Comment: Also, OP doesn't necessarily need a round function. We also don't know what kind of precision he needs. Rounding is unprecise on a certain scale (but mathematically correct). It depends what kind of precision OP is looking for. A better way would be to convert the varchar types to decimal types, and then add a format for how many decimals OP is looking for in his precision. I personally went for 2 decimals, because that's what the values themselves contain. It could always change, but point being, you don't assume the precision, but leave things as is with his current logic.

Answer (score -1):

Add a `0` to the `SUM` function it should work:

```
SELECT SUM(qty + 0) FROM inventory_logs
WHERE product_id =12 AND `type` = 'is' AND deleted_at IS null
```